# How can i tell MS Word in VBA Macros that if it finds "text" it should write me below "text2"

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I used Mailing in MS Word to make the document to fill in its template with data from Excel.

```
Sub autofill()

Dim numRecord As Integer
numRecord = InputBox("Enter number:")
Set deMain = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource

If deMain.FindRecord(FindText:=numRecord, Field:="Number") = True Then
    numRecord = deMain.ActiveRecord
End If

End Sub
```

Now I want to make it to see what is the name, and add his number in a certain place.

For example if the "Name" is "John" I want to write "885", if the "Name" is "Mary" to write "775", but I don't have these numbers in the excel and I don't want them to be there?

Comment: So where are the numbers coming from then? I am not sure I follow what the results should look like.

Comment: The numbers are coming from me. I dont want them to be in the excel table. I was thinking of writing them in the code. For example : If name == "John" (number = 885). I can attach photos if that's going to help ?

Comment: ok - so its not user input (because you have a box there that says "Enter number") and you already know, which name has which number.
You can put them in the code, but why not have a hidden Excel sheet? Correlating data is kinda Excel's thing. What's your reason for not making use of it?

Comment: I haven't thought about hidden sheets. But i don't know how to tell the Word to search through all the sheets. I can select only one sheet from "Select Recipients". The reason i don't want it in my excel is because it's a shared document and it's not allowed to input data that is not for there.

Comment: A mailmerge - which is what you're using - can only use a single worksheet as a data source.

Comment: What do you suggest me to use if not mailmerge ?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would be to insert a FILLIN field in the mailmerge main document at the point where the number is to go. Such a field might be coded as:

```
{FILLIN "Input the number" \d ""}
```

**Note:** The field brace pairs (i.e. '{ }') for the above example are all created in the document itself, via Ctrl-F9 (Cmd-F9 on a Mac or, if you’re using a laptop, you might need to use Ctrl-Fn-F9); you can't simply type them or copy & paste them from this message. Alternatively, you might insert the field via Insert|Quick Parts|Field>Fillin.